# Upload a video on Youtube by means of XHR2

Tags: youtube-api, cors, xmlhttprequest-level2

My customer wants to show progress dialog just as user is uploading video on Youtube.

I write something like:

```
    element = document.forms.uploadNewVideoForm.file;

    var fd = new FormData();
    console.log(element.files);
    fd.append('token', $scope.uploadData.token);
    fd.append('file', element.files[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", $scope.uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", $scope.uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", $scope.uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", $scope.uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.open("POST", $scope.uploadData.uploadUrl + '?nexturl=' + encodeURIComponent('http://local.app.com:8000/OK'));

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ( response ) {};
    xhr.send(fd);
```

This code start perfectly, but it fails when Youtube redirects to callback URL.

```
POST http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/<token here>?nexturl=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.app.com%3A8000%2FOK

302 Moved Temporarily 
Location: http://local.app.com:8000/OK
```

Here request interrupts and the error callback is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following [sample](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html) ([source code](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html)). It breaks the upload into two parts:

1. A CORS request to upload the metadata.
2. A form POST to upload the actual video.

Unfortunately the upload page doesn't support CORS yet, so this is the best you can do.

Comment: I want to show progress bar when video is being uploaded. If I use simple POST form, I'll not able to do this. XHR requests fails 'cause Youtube redirects to callback URL. I guess it's possible to upload using [Direct Uploading API] (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading). It also support CORS.